# Get a list of modified files in folder excluding new files from batch

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I am trying to get a "program revision count" for the last month.  I assume that the easiest way to do this, would be to get the count of modified files in the last month.  The problem with the way I am doing this, is it also lists newly created files.

I do not want newly created files, as I am looking for files that existed but were revised during the last month.

The code I wrote also gives new files, what am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off
REM set revisions folder path

 set revisions="C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\\"
 forfiles /P %revisions% /S /D +08/01/2019 > "Revisions last 30days.txt"
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong - new files modification date meets the criteria you are looking for. What you need to do is also exclude files whose creation date is newer than some date.  I'm not sure forfiles can do this.

Comment: depending on your environment and the size of files/folders it may be easier to just make a copy of the folder every thirty days, then when it comes time to check for revisions you compare the current version with the 30-day-old copy using `fc` and a `for` loop, or with a verbose `robocopy` and just parse the log file for "newer" or whatever else you want to look for (`robocopy` would also be updating your copy, so that would be a two-birds-one-stone deal - and would also capture/log deleted files which the other solutions wouldn't do).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a count (number of files) or a listing of all revised files?

A robocopy comparison between source and destination files could provide such a listing of files:

```
robocopy SourcePath DestinationPath /l /e /njh /njs /ns /xl /nc /ndl /xx /maxage:30> "Revision Last 30days.txt"
```